# Struts 2 optiontransferselect tag not working in jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I am trying to execute the following jsp code which contains the **optiontransferselect** tag. However I am getting the below exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /abc.jsp(10,0) No tag "optiontransferselect label" defined in tag library imported with prefix "s"
```

Please find the below code i have used.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Optiontransferselect Tag Example!</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form>
<s:optiontransferselect label="Employee Records" name="leftSideEmployeeRecords" leftTitle="RoseIndia" rightTitle="JavaJazzUp" list="{'Deepak Kumar', 'Sushil Kumar','Vinod Kumar','Deepak Monthy','Deepak Mihanti', 'Sushil Kumar', 'Ravi Kant Kumar'}" headerKey="headerKey" headerValue="--- Please Select ---" doubleName="rightSideEmployeeRecords" doubleList="{'Amar Deep Patel', 'Amit Kumar','Chandan Kumar', 'Noor Kumar','Tammana Kumari'}" doubleHeaderKey="doubleHeaderKey" doubleHeaderValue="--- Please Select ---" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Guide.

Comment: Struts2 version? web.xml content?

Comment: Do you use any other TLD other than Struts.

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of `struts-core-xxx.jar` in your project. Are you using `2.3.16` or above?

To use **optiontransferselect** tag you need to use struts-core-2.3.16 or higher..

Comment: Not true. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `<s:head>` tag which drags in some javascript that is needed to get the `<s:optiontransferselect>` tag to work.